# Qt - How to connect button created in QSqlRelationalDelegate

Tags: qt

I want to achieve the following: I have a MySQL table, to which I am connecting via a `QSqlRelationalTableModel`. I want the last column to get the boolean value from the database, and view buttons that are connected to actions depending on what the value of the boolean is. I created the model and the view (`tableModel` is a `MySqlTableModel`, which is a `public QSqlRelationalTableModel`):

```
tableView = new QTableView(this);
tableView->setModel(tableModel); 
tableView->setItemDelegate(new tableDelegate(this));
```

My question is, how do I connect these buttons to a function of the tableModel?

The delegate looks like this, generating the appropriate buttons:

```
void tableDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const {

    if (index.column() != 4) {
        QSqlRelationalDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
    } else if (index.model()->data(index).toInt() == 1){
        QStyleOptionButton button;
        QRect r = option.rect;//getting the rect of the cell
        int x,y,w,h;
        x = r.left() + r.width() - 90;//the X coordinate
        y = r.top();//the Y coordinate
        w = 90;//button width
        h = 30;//button height
        button.rect = QRect(x,y,w,h);
        button.text = "Logout";
        button.state = QStyle::State_Enabled;

        QApplication::style()->drawControl( QStyle::CE_PushButton, &button, painter);
    } else {
        QStyleOptionButton button;
        QRect r = option.rect;//getting the rect of the cell
        int x,y,w,h;
        x = r.left() + r.width() - 90;//the X coordinate
        y = r.top();//the Y coordinate
        w = 90;//button width
        h = 30;//button height
        button.rect = QRect(x,y,w,h);
        button.text = "Login";
        button.state = QStyle::State_Enabled;


        QApplication::style()->drawControl( QStyle::CE_PushButton, &button, painter);
    }
}
```

So, I want to connect each button `button` to `tableModel.login()` or `tableModel.logout()`, respectively. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no button. You draw button, but the button doesn't exist actually. It's just an "*image*" of button painted inside the cell.

What you can do is either insert a *real* button into the table by calling the `QAbstractItemView::setIndexWidget()` method or to connect the `QAbstractItemView::clicked()` signal to your slots.

If you decide to do it the second way, you will have to draw your pseudo button with the `QStyle::State_Sunken` when pressed, if you want it to look like a real button.

Comment: Which object should call the setIndexWidget method?

Comment: It doesn't matter that much. Let's say the object that manages the *tableView*.

Comment: If I do it with `setIndexWidget()`, all my buttons disappear as soon as I click one. Is that how it's supposed to be?